# Android: Wearable not receiving Message Api message

Tags: java, android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I am trying to send a message from an android phone to a wearable, but the onMessageReceived method in the WearableListenerService is never called.  I have verified that the message from the phone sends successfully and to the right node, so the problem appears to be on the receiving end in the wearable app.  Here is my code for the listener class in the wearable project:

```
public class MessageListener extends WearableListenerService implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
    if (messageEvent.getPath().equals("/message_path")) {
        final String message = new String(messageEvent.getData());

        // Broadcast message to wearable activity for display
        Intent messageIntent = new Intent();
        messageIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        messageIntent.putExtra("message", message);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(messageIntent);
    }
    else {
        super.onMessageReceived(messageEvent);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPeerConnected(Node peer) {
    Log.v("myTag", "Peer connected: " + peer.getDisplayName());
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Wearable.MessageApi.addListener(MainActivityWear.client, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {}
}
```

By setting breakpoints, I found that neither the onMessageReceived method nor the onConnected method were called.

Here is the MainActivity for the wearable project:

```
public class MainActivityWear extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private TextView mTextView;
private MessageReceiver messageReceiver;
public static GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_wear);
    final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
            mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
    });
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    // Register the local broadcast receiver
    IntentFilter messageFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    messageReceiver = new MessageReceiver();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(messageReceiver, messageFilter);
}
// Connect to the data layer when the Activity starts
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    client.connect();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    unregisterReceiver(messageReceiver);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {}


public class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        // Display message in UI
        mTextView.setText(message);
    }
}
}
```

The MessageReceiver is a nested class.
Everything compiles correctly, but the message is never received. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check GoogleServicesAPI's version inside application and your devices. They must be the same.

Check whether your wear and handheld devices have the same version as your app. If not - use oldest one.

PS
do not use `onPeerConnected` and `onConnectionSuspended`. Those methods are deprecated and are not fired.

Comment: Thanks, @Vyacheslav, I checked and the version is the same.  I modified the code to not include onPeerConnected and onConnectionSuspended but it is still not receiving.